# Robocopy in CMD Doesn't Copy the Parent Directory

Tags: cmd, move, robocopy

For example

- I use "robocopy /move /s /e"
- to cut C:/folder1/folder2/folder3/
- and paste into D:/library/
- but I only get D:/library/folder4/folder5/folde6

Where did folder3 go?

**edit 1**: it's supposed that within folder3 pre-exist folder4, folder5 and folder6.

**edit 2**: Here's what I'm trying... robocopy /move /s /e "%1" "D:\library"

**edit 3**: [Registry code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X8aYq.png)

**edit 4**: [Expected context menu in W10.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9SeOp.png)

Comment: Questions about how to use operating system utilities (such as `robocopy`) are best asked on superuser rather than stackoverflow (stackoverflow is really for programming questions).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The basic syntax of the Robocopy command is

`robocopy` *source-directory* *destination-directory* [*pattern*...] [*options*]

If no *pattern* is given, the default pattern is `*.*`.

The querent probably said something like

```
robocopy C:\folder1\folder2\folder3 D:\library  /move /s /e
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ ^^^^^^^^^^  ^^^^^^^^^^^
             source directory       destination    options
```

This command tells RoboCopy to move all (the default pattern in `*.*`) the files and directories it finds in `C:\folder1\folder2\folder3` to `D:\library`. Robocopy did that as expected.

To move the directory `folder3` from `C:\folder1\folder2` to `D:\library`, the command is

```
robocopy  C:\folder1\folder2\folder3  D:\library\folder3   /move /e
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   ^^^^^^^^
                source directory         destination        options
```

Robocopy will *create* the destination directory `D:\library\folder3` if needed. Note that the option `/e` implies `/s`.

Since the question appears to refer to how to do it in batch file, and assuming that `%1` does not end in a backslash, I suggest to replace `robocopy /move /s /e "%1" "D:\library"` with

```
robocopy /move /s /e "%1" "D:\library\%~nx1"
```

Comment: Hi, Alex. This is the way I also learned. Just in my case I can not insert the source folder name into the destination path, because I need the command to automate this information via folder selection.

Comment: *"I need the command to automate this information via folder selection:"* yes, all right, and? What's the difficulty?

Comment: At the moment, the difficulty is in having the destination recreate the source folder name without me explaining it literally, only via "%1" or other syntax that I do not know.

Comment: Edited the answer.

Comment: It looks like your last edit killed half the problem. I was trying to "D:\library\%1"  and I only got the folder to disappear. With your suggestion "D:\library\%~nx1" I was able to create the folder with the original structure, except for its name, which has now been named "%~nx1". I have attached some photos to clarify better.

Comment: Ah, now I understand. You are trying to use the command directly in the definition of a menu entry. It won't work there; you need to pass the pathnames of the source and destination directories to a batch script.

Answer (score 0):

The `/MOVE` option deleted the source folder, *folder3* in this case, after copying to the new destination.

I see you are using both `/s` and `/e`. I think you may want to simplify your command and choose either `/s`, which will not copy empty directories, or `/e` which WILL copy empty directories.

Comment: Hi, Nathan. I guess I forgot to say that folder4, folder5 and folder6 were originally inside folder3. I want to automate a command that does the same thing when we select a folder and click CRTL+X CTRL+V to move it, hence the need to preserve the empty folders if they existed in the original structure.